# Strange Mixed Content Issue

Tags: security, xmlhttprequest, mixed-content

I've been having this error in Chrome Developer Tools for a while and I just can't seem to find the insecure http:// request. It points to my domain but without https://.  http://www.example.com/ is not a script so I don't understand where it's coming from.

**Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.example.com/categoy/a-product.html' 
was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.example.com/'. This request has been blocked; 
the content must be served over HTTPS.**

**Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.example.com/categoy/a-product.html' 
was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://www.example.com/'. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Is the page you are hosting a single page application with HTML5/history/push-state routing?

This type of routing goes by many names, but what it does is replace your hash-based url `https://address.com/page/#client/side/route` with regular routes such as `https://address.com/page/client/side/route`. When the files are hosted with a static file server, the file server may not know about the client-side routing and return a 404 instead of routing everything to `index.html`. Apparently, this can lead to the problem you described in Chrome even though the page might appear to work.

In short, many static file hosting tools are not suitable to serve a SPA with HTML5 routing, notably http-server (https://github.com/indexzero/http-server/issues/80). Try a different tool (e.g. `serve`) or use nginx with `try_files $uri $uri/ index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

This means your web page is being accessed over https, but it uses resources that are served over http. Modern browsers like Chrome consider this as a security risk. The browser does not load the http resources and shows a warning in the developers console.

The solution is to change the protocol method from http to https for all resources that are being accessed over http.

See this link: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content#alternatives_to_csp